# "Undefined method 'delete' for nil:NilClass" in Sinatra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra, erb

I'm working on a project in Sinatra and I can't seem to get the delete method to work. My intent is to be able to remove an object using a form in a modal. Here's what I have:

routes.rb:

```
  delete '/songs/:id/delete' do

     @song = Song.where(:id => params[:id]).first

     @song.delete

     redirect to '/songs'

  end
```

index.erb:

```
 <form action="/songs/:id/delete" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete">
          <div id="song_id">
            <label>id:</label>
            <input type="text" name="id">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="delete">Delete</button>
          <a href="/songs"><div id="back">Back to Songs</div></a>
        </form>
```

Feedback is appreciated. 
(Also, sorry indentation isn't perfect)

Comment: In your controller `@song` is `nil`(because a Song with the given `id` could not be found). Check whether `Song.where...` actually returns something before working on it (via `.delete`). See B Sevens answer for why your id is not correct.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject the id into the form. Not `:id`.

```
 # example
 <form action="/songs/1234/delete" method="post">
```

Also, you can see what is happening with `puts params`.